# Iterar um lista e verificar se existe o componente em jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou realizando uma chamada Ajax e, com isso, retornando novos cadastros para uma tabela. Até aí tudo bem, mas quero realizar um `.prepend()` adicionando um botão de "Remover" em cada elemento da lista.

O problema é que esse `button` é adicionado apenas no primeiro `li`

Tentei fazer rodar no jsFiddle mas não estou conseguindo. Logo, tentei postar o código abaixo de forma simplificada:

O **fluxo** é simples:

- Cliente clica em um botão para adicionar um novo usuário;
- Uma Modal é aberta com alguns campos;
- Logo que é dado o Submit, eu faço uma chamada Ajax enviando os valores;
- É retornado um JSON, o qual contém um resultado que vou adicionar em uma lista na tela;

**Problema**

- Eu faço um `$().each()` seguido de `if` para verificar se meu botão de "remover" já existe naquela linha;
- O mesmo só adiciona o botão no primeiro registro.

**Código**

```
$('#modal-form').submit(function(e) {
    var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/addPassenger?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#modal-form").serialize(),
        success: function(jsonData) {

            if (jsonData != "") {
                var passenger = jsonData.firstName;

                $('#passenger-list').append('<li id="list-all-passenger" ><label>' + passenger + '</label></li>');

                $('#passenger-list li').each(function(i) {
                    if (this, $('#button-cancel-passenger').length) {

                    } else {
                        $(this).prepend('<button id="button-cancel-passenger" type="reset" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" style="position: relative; top: -1px;"><span class="entypo-cancel-squared"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Remover</button>');
                    }

                });

                $('#myModal').modal('hide');

                $('#passenger-name').val('');
                $('#passenger-lastName').val('');
                $('#passenger-email').val('');
                $('#passenger-phone').val('');
                $('#passenger-birth').val('');
                $('#passenger-rg').val('');
                $('#passenger-cpf').val('');
            } else {
                if ($('#div-error-passenger').length) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $('#div-modal-input-body').prepend('<div id="div-error-passenger" class="alert alert-info box03"></div>');
                    $('#div-error-passenger').append('<span id="span-error-passenger" class="entypo-info-circled"></span> <b>Você Precisa preencher no mínimo o nome e sobrenome do passageiro!</b>.');
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: não leva a mal, mas por que tu tem um `if` vazio???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no seu If `if(this, $('#button-cancel-passenger').length)`.

Exemplo do mesmo IF funcionando.

```
$('ul > li').each(function () {
    var button = $(this).find("button");
    if (! button.length) {
        $(this).prepend('<button>Remover</button>');
    }
});
```

Recomendo que você de uma lida sobre a diferença entre IDs e Classes no HTML. Ids sempre devem ser únicos.

Comment: Legal @R. Eitz funcionou legal. Aproveitando o embalo que você comentou sobre id's nos componetes. Qual seria a melhro forma de gerar id's dinamicos com o jQuery? Pois vou ter que trabalhar isso junto com o JAVA